# How to join multiple tables (SQL) to find the difference between an order and shipped quantities?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a collection of orders that were submitted to an internal ERP, which were processed and partially shipped.

The table hierarchy is as follows:

- `Order` table contains `OrderReference(PO), OrderID`
- `OrderItems` table contains `Product/Lot/Qty` requested (`OrderID` is `parentID` that joins these tables)
- `Shipping` contains `OrderReference(PO), ShippingID`
- `ShippingArchive` contains `Product/Lot/Qty` that was shipped (`ShippingID` is parent that joins these tables)

I want to create a report that looks as follows:

```
OrderReference#

Order Requested / Shipped Items / Missing Pieces

PC/Lot/Qty    -   PC/Lot/Qty    - PC/Lot/Qty
```

I have used a temp table to get some of the data but I realize I'm taking the wrong approach. I should be able to do all of this with a single query, though it will seemingly be a bit complex.

I get held up when I try to think about how to join where pieces don't exist, and where to perform the mathematics in my sorting and filtering. Please help!

Sincere thanks :)

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22b09/3) and see if it gets you close

Comment: Can you post some data with DDL and expected results ? That will help answer accurately.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want.  I had to make a few assumptions though.  First that a given item is identified by `product` and `lot`.  So I added a join between `ShippingArchive` and `OrderItems` based on these columns.   Next that in your report you only needed to see the `product` and `lot` information once and needed the `requested`, `shipped` and `missing` information for `qty` only.  I also made the assumption that `missing` meant `requested-shipped`.

Edited to handling multiple shipping for the same order.

```
WITH Shipped AS (SELECT Shipping.OrderReference, ShippingArchive.Product, ShippingArchive.lot, 
                        SUM(ShippingArchive.qty) AS Qty
                FROM Shipping
                JOIN ShippingArchive
                    ON Shipping.ShippingId = ShippingArchive.ShippingId
                GROUP BY Shipping.OrderReference, ShippingArchive.Product, ShippingArchive.lot
                )
SELECT  [Order].OrderReference, OrderItems.Product AS Requested_Product, OrderItems.lot AS Requested_Lot, OrderItems.qty AS Requested_Qty, 
    ISNULL(Shipped.qty,0) AS Shipped_Qty, OrderItems.qty - ISNULL(Shipped.qty,0) AS Missing_Qty
FROM [Order]
JOIN OrderItems
    ON [Order].OrderId = OrderItems.OrderId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Shipped
    ON [Order].OrderReference = Shipped.OrderReference
    AND OrderItems.Product = Shipped.Product
    AND OrderItems.Lot = Shipped.Lot
```

Comment: Does this take care if a product was shipped (partially) in different shippings?

Comment: Good point.  I'll add that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Select oi.ProductCode,oi.Lot,oi.Qty,isnull(shipped.qty,0), oi.Qty - IsNull(shipped.qty,0) as MissingQty
From OrderItems oi left Join
(
Select shipping.OrderID,sa.ProductCode, sa.Lot,sa.Qty From OrderItems
From ShippingArhive sa
inner join Shipping On Shipping.ShipID = sa.ShipID
) shipped
On oi.OrderID = shipped.OrderID and oi.ProductCode = shipped.ProductCode and oi.Lot = Shipped.Lot
```

maybe?